# Definition by minimization in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, induction

Assume `P: nat -> T -> Prop` is a proposition that for any given `t: T`,

- either there exists a `k: nat` such that `P` holds for all numbers greater than or equal to `k` and no number less than `k`.
- or `P k t` is false for all `k : nat`.

I want to define `min_k : T -> nat + undef` to be the minimum number `k` such that `P k t` holds, and `undef` otherwise.

Is that even possible? I tried to define something like

```
Definition halts (t : T) := exists k : nat, P k t.
```

Or maybe

```
Definition halts (t : T) := exists! k : nat, (~ P k t /\ P (S k) t).
```

and then use it like

```
Definition min_k (t : T) := match halts T with
  | True => ??
  | False => undef
end.
```

but I don't know how to go further from there.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `match` on a `Prop`. If you want to do case analysis then you need something in `Type`, typically `bool` or something like [`sumbool`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Specif.html#sumbool) or [`sumor`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Specif.html#sumor). In other words, you can do what you want as long as you have a pretty strong hypothesis.

```
Variable T : Type.
Variable P : nat -> T -> Prop.

Hypothesis PProperty : forall (t : T),
  {k : nat | forall n, (k <= n -> P n t) /\ (n < k -> ~ P n t)}
  +
  {forall k, ~ P k t}.

Definition min_k (t : T) : option nat :=
  match PProperty t with
  | inleft kH => Some (proj1_sig kH)
  | inright _ => None
  end.
```

Crucially, this wouldn't have worked if `PProperty` was a `Prop` disjunction, i.e., if it was of the form `_ \/ _` instead of the form [`_ + { _ }`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Specif.html#sumor).

By the way, the idiomatic way of describing `foo + undef` in Coq is to use [`option foo`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Datatypes.html#option), which is what I did above, but you can adapt it as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can I ask for a reference to read more about the `proj1_sig`?

Comment: I think the hypothesis can be simplified with a trivial one that is correct for any P in classical logic.
`Hypothesis PProperty : forall (t : T),
  {k : nat | (P k t) /\ forall n, (n < k -> ~ P n t)}
  +
  {forall k, ~ P k t}.`

Comment: In general if you don't know what something does you can `Check proj1_sig` to see its type, `Print proj1_sig` to see its definition, or even `Locate proj1_sig` to find out where it is defined. The latter is useful to see if there are some helpful comments in the code next to the definition. [In this case](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Specif.html#proj1_sig) there are: we see that `proj1_sig` is the first projection of `sig`, which is a `Type` version of `exists _, _`. So `proj1_sig kH` gives you the `k` for which the property holds.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "classical logic". Usually I'd say it means "Coq + `forall P : Prop, P \/ ~ P`". Note that this is *weaker* than `forall P : Prop, {P} + {~ P}`, which I believe is what you need to assume in order to obtain your `PProperty`. You can still work under the stronger assumption, but be aware of which axioms you under.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ana's excellent answer, I think it is worth pointing out that `option nat` is essentially the same thing as `{k : nat | ...} + {forall k, ~ P k t}` if you erase the proofs of the latter type: in the first case (`Some` or `inleft`), you get a natural number out; in the second (`None` or `inright`) you get nothing at all.

Comment: Wow. I didn't look at it that way! Thank you for pointing out this point. But I am struggling to understand what does it mean being the same thing. The `...` in the left side should be true I think if we want it to be all of `nat`?

Comment: @KamyarMirzavaziri Just to make things simple, consider the following declaration: `Inductive t (P : nat -> Prop) : Type := inleft : forall n, P n -> t P | inright : (forall n, ~ P n) ->  t P`. By choosing the value of `P` appropriately, you can obtain a type that is pretty much like the one you had in `PProperty`. Each constructor of this type takes as an argument a proof that a certain proposition holds. If you remove these two arguments from the declaration, you end up with a definition that is isomorphic to `option nat`.